# What are the cosets of $\mathbb{Q_8} / Z(\mathbb{Q_8})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quaternions

$\mathbb{Q_8} = \{\pm 1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k\}$ where 1 is the identity and $\mathbb{Q_8}$ is a non-abelian group under ordinary multiplication

---

Let it be given that $i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1$

---

I already calculated $Z(\mathbb{Q_8}) = \{-1, 1 \}$ by constructing a Cayley table

---

I want to find $\mathbb{Q_8} / Z(\mathbb{Q_8})$

---

Now, I know Lagrange's theorem tells us that $\mid \mathbb{Q_8} / Z(\mathbb{Q_8}) \mid = 8/2 =4$. So there must be 4 distinct cosets

---

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Aren't they just $\{\pm1\},\{\pm i\},\{\pm j\},\{\pm k\}$?  $\;\{\pm1\}$ is the identity element in the quotient group

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, that's what I'm asking. and how to show that that is true

Comment: All you have to do is list the cosets: $\{i, -i\}$ is one of them. I am sure you can list the other three.

Comment: ... and to construct the multiplication table, write the multiplication table for $\Bbb{Q}_8$ with the elements listed as $1, -1, i, -i, j, -j, k, -k$. Then you can get the multiplication table for the quotient group by subdividing the multiplication table for $\Bbb{Q}_8$ into $2\times 2$ blocks.

Comment: For example, $i\{1,-1\}=\{i,-i\}=-i\{1,-1\}$, so $i$ and $-i$ are in the same coset $\{i,-i\}$, and so on.

Comment: Don’t use the blackboard bold $Q$ for the quaternions; it’s reserved for the rationals, and then $\mathbb{Q}_8$ looks like an attempt at “$8$-adic rationals” (which don’t exist). The usual notation for the quaternion group of eight elements is simply $Q_8$.

Answer (score 2):

The congruence classes modulo a a normal subgroup are obtained multiplying each element of the group by all elements of the subgroup. Therefore, it is not hard to check that you obtain the four classes
$$\{1,-1\},\; \{i,-i\}, \; \{j,-j\}, \; \{k,-k\}.$$
Furthermore, the quotient $Q_8/Z$  is abelian, and each class has order $2$, so $Q_8/Z$ is isomorphic to Klein's Vierer Gruppe.

Comment: Is it really hard to check that? $\ddot{\smile}$? (And I think you have more "er"s than you need in the name of the group.).

Comment: Not really hard. Sorry for the typo – I forgot to check evrything was OK. As  to the spelling of Klein's group, I've always seen it this way.

Comment: My rudimentary knowledge of German was wrong about [vierergruppe](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/50079/is-it-vierergruppe-or-viergruppe-or-is-there-a-distinction]) it seems.